# Include Review,Rating and Images in places API

Tags: here-api

I am implementing Places rest api, In request i have included show_content and show_refs like

```
https://...v1/places/...&show_content=wikipedia&show_refs=tripadvisor,facebook
```

I m receiving object with TripAdvisor id in response but rating and review objects are always empty.

However when i try to search same place on wego.here.com i can see the reviews and images in response from TripAdvisor, and there is no difference in my api call. How i can get data in these objects from here.com.

Do i need to implement facebook graph api or TripAdvisor content api and use TripAdvisor id to get the additional content like images,reviews from external sources.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as stated in the Places (Search) API documentation, you only get the place/location IDs of external systems (TripAdvisor, etc) in responses. With the IDs, you can retrieve other details (such images, reviews, etc) from external system APIs (in this case the TripAdvisor API).

https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics_api/resource-search.html