# Why am I not receiving any images from the HERE Places (Search) API?

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

I'm trying to get images for restaurants using the HERE Places (Search) API.

I'm using the "Browse" entrypoint, and then using the href in there to get a restaurant's details. In it, I keep on getting this:

```
media: {
 images: {
  available:0
  items: [ ]
}
```

The same for reviews and ratings.

Based on other posts here, I'm confused what the problem is, as one [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62142786/here-sdk-flutter-does-not-show-places-image-always-returns-no-data-for-images) seemingly says its a bug, and one [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57969161/include-review-rating-and-images-in-places-api) seemingly says it's just the way the API is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, "HERE Places API" is deprecated. You should migrate to "HERE Geocoding and Search API v7". Check this out https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/migration_guide/index.html

As already explained in this question
[Include Review,Rating and Images in places API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57969161/include-review-rating-and-images-in-places-api) , the API will return the place IDs of external suppliers (TripAdvisor, Yelp etc). This is true also for the latest "HERE Geocoding and Search API v7". With these IDs, you can retrieve other details (such images, reviews, etc) from external system APIs.